# Routing to a view (twig file) without calling a function?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Y have this /src/AppBundle/Resources/views/tests/index.html.twig which just contains:

```
{{text}}
```

And is controlled from /src/AppBundle/Controller/TestsController.php which was working fine with a Route over the function that renders "text". Now i want to have a routes file which I've located at /src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml. Apparently in older versions this could be done with:

```
tests_index:
    path: /tests/index
    defaults: [_controller: AppBundle:Tests:index]
```

But maybe I'm missing something or the newer Symfony isn't buying it when I try to reach it at http://localhost/project/web/tests/index. The error is:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/pruebas/index". The route is
>   wrongly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of your question is rather strange, because you do want to use a controller.  Anyway, your config is not right. It should look like this:

```
tests_index:
    path:     /tests/index
    controller: App\Controller\TestsController::show
```

In this case `show` is the name of the function in your controller. 
Also I would advise to use routing annotations. It makes life much easier. Read more about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html).

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that I want to route to the file without having to point to a method. In my case the code following your indications is:

`pruebas_index:
    path: /pruebas/index
    controller: AppBundle\Controller\PruebasController:indexAction`  

But I don't want to have to point to "indexAction". Anyway, I had it solved with annotations before, but thought that a routing file was cleaner, better. Can't be done without pointing to the metod? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The whole framework is build that you have to have a function/method in your controller for each action.

Comment: considering the annotations, I most definitely prefer this method, but it is up to you, it does not really matter.

Comment: Hmmm sorry, you are right. I'm just trying to learn to use it but I actually don't know it's phylosophy. I'll read about it before going on.

Thanks!

Comment: check this page for more info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html. And if you are just beginning I also recommend this (free) tutorial: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony/setup